# Trouble with basic networking of an Ubuntu Linux server edition server

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, internet, dns

As an introduction, what I am trying to do is get my Linux Ubuntu server online and start sharing files with the internet and locally with my family, hosting Wordpress.org pages, and other things of that nature.

I created a new file for output of commands that would produce useful results for anyone wishing to help debug my issue by using the touch command, and `ls -l` lists that `u` of this file has `w` access, but when I write the output of a command to the file, it states `Permission denied`. So I will be paraphrasing the output of relevant commands here in hopes it is still informative.

---

`uname -a`:

`Linux diogenes 4.15.0-55-generic #60-ubuntu SMP [date] x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

---

`ifconfig -a`:

`eno1` (my ethernet connection): among other things, states that it is `UP`, `RUNNING`, has an `inet6` address (appears to be IPv6), an `ether` address (appears to be IPv6), and actually does receive and transmit packets to and from the router (I'm not sure what these packets are, they could be maintenance packets or just like, messages that literally say "You're not connected to the internet", which wouldn't be all too useful).

`lo`: typical loopback details, nothing seems awery

---

`ip link`:

`lo` and `eno1`. `lo` looks normal, `eno1` has a `link/ether` value that is the same as the `ether` ipv6 address as above in `ifconfig`. `UP`, `LOWER_UP` flags enabled among others, and `state` is `UP`, `mode` is `DEFAULT`. Can provide additional details upon request, just don't feel like dictating the whole thing.

---

`route`:

The routing table is empty!

---

The documentation that came with the router I have connected to my wall states its IPv4 address is `9.9.9.9`, and that it doesn't seem to have an ipv6 address. The wall is connected to the leftmost socket on the router, called CONSOLE, spaced apart from the other sockets so I would assume this is where internet comes into the router. I plugged the server into socket 1 out of 4 to the right. PWR and SYS LEDs are green solid, ALM LED is off, and LED under socket 1 is solid on. Documentation states the router has WiFi capabilities but when I enter 9.9.9.9 on my laptop in a web browser, nothing is found. It's a Cisco router with a powered fan so it sounds nice.

---

`sudo ip route add default via 9.9.9.9`:

`Error: Nexthop has invalid gateway`.

---

Here are the contenst of my `netplan` file:

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        eno1:
            dhcp4: true
            dhcp6: tre
            nameservers:
                addresses: [8.8.8.8]
```

---

`ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com`:

`Temporary failure in name resolution`

`ping -c3 www.msn.com`:

`Temporary failure in name resolution`

`ping -c3 8.8.8.8`:

`connect: Network is unreachable`

`ping -c3 127.0.0.1`:

Ping succeeds.

---

My ISP is Comcast (Xfinity). The family's router downstairs and the WiFi works for like regular computers, I have Ubuntu with a GUI on my laptop, all the chromebooks/Windows machines in the house work on the family wifi connection no problem. I strive not to mess up any of the family's business or connectivity, but I suppose if situations were dire I might be able to gain access to the router downstairs and do some port forwarding or whatever. But really, I'd rather not--asking Dad for the router's login information would arouse suspicion and I WOULD probably mess it up at some point, and that would just end up in an unpleasant argument. I'd like to use the router in my room for use with my laptop and server if possible. I don't know how this interfaces with my ISP, assuming all network connectivity in the house (all ethernet and cable wall sockets) are serviced by the ISP anyway, I would assume you should be able to do it without their equipment?

---

Any other output or clarification anyone needs?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Advice: You can safely practice basic networking and server admin without mucking with your real network at all: Install a Virtual Machine on to your laptop. After a bit of playing in a VM Guest or two, you will find real-world networking and server operation MUCH easier to understand and troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll look into it. For now, I'm still pretty interested in working on real machinery.

Comment: What is the make/model of your router? A "console" port is not usually the same as a WAN port.